# Fast Search Server For SharePoint 2010 Sorting Turkish Character Problem

Tags: fast-search

I want to sort "DisplayName" column which is type of string. DisplayName column has a managed property which have sortable and queryable property. DisplayName colomn has some Turkish character. I used for sorting below XML.

```
<SortByProperties>
  <SortByProperty name="rstdisplayname" direction="Ascending" />
</SortByProperties>
```

After send Query to QueryEx web service method, Query returns incorrect sorting.
Without included turkish Character string record return correct, but turkish character string return in last result record. You can see at below example.

Result Example Below.

1.İstanbul

2.Ömerli

3.Çankırı

4.Zeytinburnu

5.Yozgat

6.Bursa

7.Ankara

Normally result must be below:

1.Zeytinburnu

2.Yozgat

3.Ömerli

4.İstanbul

5.Çankırı

6.Bursa

7.Ankara

How can I sort Correctly?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Could you please post your whole Query Packet?

Answer (score 1):

Now I solve problem. İt’s working  correctly.

default FAST search sort is based on ASCII sort order. We must to change deployment-ready-index-profile.xml  to full sort profile.
Therefore I change deployment-ready-index-profile.xml in sortable managed property like below.

Before(Default):

Changed(set profile generic ) :

I find this information below msdn link.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pasen/archive/2011/03/08/case-insensitive-sort-order-in-fast-search-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx